Why does sendto reverse my IP address when using network byte order?
I'm trying to send a multicast UDP packet to the IP address 239.255.0.1. I have a ConnectionAttributes class that stores IP addresses and can return them in either network byte order (NBO) or host byte order (HBO).
Here are the values for the IP 239.255.0.1 in both formats:
IP: 239.255.0.1
NBO: 4026466305 (0xEFFF0001)
HBO: 16842735 (0x0100FFEF)

This is the C++ snippet I’m using to send the data over a socket:
Error UDPConnectionHandler::send(const void *data, size_t dataSize) {

    auto nbo = 4026466305; // 239.255.0.1 in network byte order
    auto hbo = 16842735; // 239.255.0.1 in host byte order

    sockaddr_in destAddr = {};
    destAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destAddr.sin_port = 59420;
    destAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = nbo;
    ssize_t bytesSent;

    bytesSent = sendto(connAttr.getSocket(), data, dataSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&destAddr, sizeof(destAddr));

    if (bytesSent == -1)
          return Error(ERROR_ERRNO, errno);

    return Error(ERR_SUCCESS);
}

I use inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr) to get the network byte order from an IP given as a const char*. To convert this address into host network order, I am using ntohl. I am on a Little Endian system.
But, if I provide the IP in host byte order (16842735), the packet is correctly sent with the IP address 239.255.0.1.
My understanding is that sendto should take network byte order. Why is it reversing the IP address when I provide it in network byte order? What am I missing here?

What is NetworkByteOrder? What is HostByteOrder? How are they initialized? What does connAttr.getAddress() really do? Can you please try to create a proper [mre] to show us?

These are simple enums. To avoid confusion I can simpliy the example.

And are you on a little-endian system or a big-endian? How do you get the values for the host and network byte order values? How do you do the IP address to value conversion?

Presumably NetworkByteOrder is not in network byte order, but since you haven't showed us how it is defined or specified whether your system is big endian or little endian it's hard to say. My guess is that there is some confusion or unawareness of the endianness of your platform.

"I thought that the IP address must be provided in network byte order when using sendto" - that is correct.

You are confusing the external representation with the internal representation. Your CPU is little-endian, so your "NBO" 0xEFFF0001 is actually stored as the following sequence of bytes:
01 00 FF EF

htonl(0xEFFF0001) is the proper way to compute the network byte order. It will byteswap on little-endian systems and do nothing on big-endian systems (but those are rare anyway).
As a general rule, you should only work with IP addresses in host order and swap to/from network order when you send/receive.

Thank you. A call inet_pton promises me to convert my IP to network byte order (big endian). Since I am on a little endian system, it is actually stored in little endian and I have to revert endianess again using htonl!? The name htonl indiciates that it converts host byte order to network byte order. This means, inet_pton converts to host byte order?

inet_pton is a more generic API that also supports IPv6 and other network protocols. It also converts from host to network, but it treats addresses as strings of bytes instead of the (very confusing) integers.

The API says it precisely: "inet_aton() converts the Internet host address cp from the IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary form (in network byte order)". If the address is indeed provided in network byte order (big endian), I would expect that I can directly use it without calling htonl. This is the confusing part for me...
If inet_pton stored the IP in host byte order, everything would be clear.

The "numbers and dots notation" is a char* of the form "XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW", not a number. It is the human-readable representation of the address, and there is only one order to do it in: network order.

Yes, I know that this is human-readable representation. But I struggle with the fact that inet_aton supposedly converts into network byte order. Why should I call then htonl that converts from host byte order to network byte order. Thank you

You don't need to! inet_pton is an alternative way of getting an IP address in network order (for direct consumption by sendto and recv or a sockaddr_*.
